# Passing an NSManagedObject's property reference to another viewcontroller to edit value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Issue: I have a standard subclassed NSManagedObject (see below). I have a view controller I'd like to use to edit all of the NSString* 's of the NSManagedObject. I only want to pass a reference to the pointer of any of the NSString* 's below to edit. How can do I do this? Is there a better way to setup editing screens and references? Right now I'm passing the entire NSManagedObject * to the editing ViewController, then do a hack job of using an integer to update/edit the correct property I want to edit from the NSManagedObject.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? I've yet to see a nice clean example of working with editing entities from core data and am relatively new to interface design.

NSManagedObject:

```
@interface MySounds : NSManagedObject {

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * soundOne;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * soundTwo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * soundThree;
```

The Edit Interface:

```
@interface EditItemViewController : UIViewController
<UITextViewDelegate>
{
    MySounds *sounds;
    int fieldToEdit;
    ...
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) MySounds *toSave;
@property (nonatomic) int fieldToEdit;
```

Example of how I use the int and MySounds *:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   switch (fieldToEdit)
   {
   ...
   case 2:
   {
      [self.textField setText:[self.sounds soundOne]];
   }
   ...
   }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. Nevermind the entire question.

I forgot about key-value coding with nsmanagedobjects :)